# React-navigation 4.x - navigation.state.routes is undefined

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

A couple of days ago react-navigation started breaking the navigation UI of my job's app, so I decided to updated to `4.1.1` since I use it for my personal projects and works great.

After upgrading it, the UI started working fine but I am having an error with `navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index].routeName` and `navigation.state.routes.length` coming out as undefined.

Now I know navigation.state used to have: `index, isTransitioning, key, params, routeName, routes.key, routes.routeName` now its only `key, params and routeName`.

I figured out how to solve the routeName but the app custom nav components are heavily dependent on the `navigation.state.routes.length` does anyone know the equivalent of this?

I am using:

- expo: sdk36 (jobs app)
- react-native: 0.61 (side projects)
- react-navigation: 4.1.1
- react-navigation-stack: 2.1.1
- react-navigation-tabs: 2.7.0

The documentation of 4.x also shows `navigation.state.index` which is undefined... here is an example of what I tried so far:

```
{
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    header: ({ navigation, navigationState }) => {
      console.log(navigation.state) <-- key, param and routeName
      console.log(navigationState) <-- undefined
    }
```

I wish react-navigation 4.x docs were better organized like the 5.x.

Please this is sort of an emergency any insight is helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem with `4.4.0`. I know this question is a bit old, but I hope this will at least help you or somebody with solving the problem.

After `console.log` -ing the `navigation.state` I see that it only contains `routeName` and `key`.

I am using typescript and my type annotations were showing that all the properties you are referencing should be in the state object.

After a long search I found this [answer in issue on GitHub](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/962#issuecomment-310390002) which seems to be addresing just the mentioned problem. Although it is a bit old and offers no explanation, the given issue might have some insight into the problem.

The solution mentioned in the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/962#issuecomment-310390002) suggest something like this:

```
if (navState.hasOwnProperty('index')) {  
    routeName = navState.routes[navState.index].routeName
    console.log("Current Route Name:", routeName)
} else {
    console.log("Current Route Name:", navState.routeName)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the state from its parent navigation with

```js
navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().state
```